# Как мне использовать метод класса Input в файле Window.h, если тот уже подключает файл Input.h и наоборот

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> файл Window.h

```
#include Input.h;
            class Menu : public Window {
                protected:
                    Array<String> items;
                    Input inp;
```

> файл Input.h

```
             #include "Window .h";
                    //пытался так, не получилось
                    class Window;  
                    class Input {
                    private:
                        Window w;
```

Comment: Файлы не могут инклудить друг друга по кругу, но здесь это и не нужно. Подозреваю, что в `Input` достаточно указателя на window, а чтобы его сделать, инклудить хедер не нужно.

Comment: можете написать подробней, у меня вообще есть статическая переменная size, я ее ввожу в файле window.cpp, затем мне нужно в файле input получить этот размер, но выбивает ошибку при попытке создать  объект класса window

Comment: и вот я не совсем понимаю как получить эту переменную в этом файле